# Jquery animate and internet explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have problem with internet explorer only , i tested this in ie 8 and 9

The problem it´s for example i have one div container with position absolute and i can see behind of other div in position relative , ok , all this perfect

The problem for example come when i use jquery for create effect with animate of opacity

```
$('body').animate({
opacity: 0.90
});
```

When i do this , in internet explorer all these divs cover for the effect of body and i can´t see , but this problem for example no happen in other brownsers as chrome or firefox , the code it´s very long by this no put all here , if it´s necessary i put no problem

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: Would you happen to have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example of what's going on?

Comment: I try , but the code it´s very long , regards

Comment: Nobody wants you to post too much code... that would be counterproductive.  But so far, you've really posted nothing.  **Surely you can post just enough of the relevant HTML so that a concise demo can be constructed.**

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
$('body').fadeTo(.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify an animation length and make sure it is inside a document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').animate({opacity: 0.90}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Ok i go try this code , and tell something now , thank´s

Comment: No , happend other time the same , cover the other divs , if no put this animation no problem , if i put it internet explorer works bad and cover the divs the opacity effect and in the other as chrome or firefox no have this issue , regards

Comment: Can you include some code?